Trying to understand rust's magic in std::path::Path::as_ref
the following implementation is from the Rust Standard Library (https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/path.rs.html#3289):
impl AsRef<Path> for str {
    #[inline]
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &Path {
        Path::new(self)
    }
}

As far as I understand the code, the function should return a reference (according to the signature), but it seems to return an owned object.
There are now two things I don't understand:

Why is the owned object 'automatically' converted into a reference
Why does this not produce runtime errors, when the owned object runs
out of scope and is dropped when the function returns


Path::new returns &Path.

There's a few different misconceptions at play here. Let's unpack some of them:

Why is the owned object 'automatically' converted into a reference

There's nothing owned here. Path is not an owned struct, PathBuf is. The value is already a reference.

Why does this not produce...errors, when the owned object runs out of scope and is dropped?

Because again there isn't an owned value here. This method takes a reference to a string slice (str) noted here as &self, and returns a Path reference based on it. It won't be invalidated until the memory underlying the string slice goes out of scope. You can see this in action by forcing such a failure:
use std::path::Path;

fn fails<'a>(s: String) -> &'a Path {
    let r: &str = &s;
    r.as_ref() // will fail here, s goes out of scope
}

// N.B. no lifetime param, lifetime is implicitly the lifetime
// of the memory underlying the string slice
fn works(s: &str) -> &Path {
    s.as_ref()
}

fn main() {
    let s = String::from("/hi");
    let p = works(&s);
    println!("{:?}", p); // prints "/hi" if you comment out fails
    let f = fails(s);    // compile error
    println!("{:?}", f); // doesn't run
}

The fails function here takes ownership of the String, so when the function ends the s parameter goes out of scope and the returned reference is invalidated, which is why the borrow checker refuses to compile this code. That code shows that your intuition about this sort of thing has some merit.
But works still, well, works: there's no transfer of memory ownership so the compiler can infer that the lifetime of the reference is the same as the underlying string slice and responds accordingly. (It may also be worth noting here that you don't have to explicitly pass a type parameter to the as_ref call because the compiler can tell from the return type of the fn that you want a Path reference). This is more or less what's going on in the code that surprised you.
Also as one last aside on terminology, you keep saying "object". That isn't necessarily bad: a Rust struct with methods will match some of your intuitions about objects from, say, Java. But not all of them. The lack of garbage collection will frustrate some of your intuitions here if you're coming from a managed language (I know that was true for me), and if you have no experience of something like Traits from a functional language (e.g. Scala Traits, Haskell Typeclasses) that too can trip you up (and is maybe doing so here).
Be careful how much weight you give to Rust-struct-instances-as-object-analogs in your mental model.

Thank you for the explanation.
The fact that there are not only owned structs but also structs which are references is new to me.
Is there some "black magic" in the standard library that allows to do this ?
When I try to resemble such a struct in my own code, it always fails during compiling because of lifetime issues.

@Gerhard77 there's no black magic, at least not at that level: Path is just a wrapper with a bunch of impls around OsStr which is just a wrapper with a bunch of impls around a slice. "When I try to resemble such a struct in my own code, it always fails during compiling because of lifetime issues" did you try making a wrapper struct around an intrinsically unsized type like str? Because that should work fine... the other failure mode for this is trying to aggregate multiple refs in a single struct, because then it's unclear to the compiler which reference's lifetime to infer....

Don't be so quick to assume that something is the result of compiler magic: Rust is complicated and it is challenging to build a detailed enough mental model of its complexities. When you encounter something you struggle to do the problem is more likely to be in your mental model than some fundamental limit to the langauge that has to be handled in the compiler for built-in stuff.

After some investigations in the std library (which is indeed complicated) I manged to find out how these "wrappers" that are created when calling "Path::new(self)" work: Basically they are just doing typecasts in the form of
struct Struct1{
pub value: String,
}
struct Struct2{
value: String,
}
fn convert(val: &Struct1) -> &Struct2{
unsafe { &*(val as *const Struct1 as *const Struct2) }
}
